# How can I include suggestions like from Google suggest in my own auto complete box

Tags: jquery, html, autocomplete

The following code shows an auto complete function which only uses the data which I have given. I want to be able to change the data source so that when using the auto complete, common Google searches will be displayed. How could I do this?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript"
        src="http://www.google.com/jsapi?key=ABQIAAAARh4zAaoctlNef6M1fBHLSRT_pkQkDorgHY-QpTBEqS9oVy079BTA6a35AAdpXz6ExAMdICz8lNWRVA"></script>
        <script>
            google.load("jquery", "1.4.2");
            google.load("jqueryui", "1.8.2");
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var myData = ["One", "Two", "Three"];
                    $("#myTestField").autocomplete({
                        source: myData
                    });
                });
        </script>

        <form>
        <input type="text" id="myTestField" />
        </form>

    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the sample code possibilities are defined in the myData array. You need to set up a php (or any other technology) serverside script to return data based on a starting string. That data will be polled through AJAX and used by the autocomplete.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find the sample code that intuitive to do this myself so I'll put something basic here for an autocomplete search box using ASP.NET MVC.

jquery:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#search").autocomplete({
            source: '/Search'
        });
    });
</script>
```

ASP.NET MVC:

```
public ActionResult Search(string term)
{
    List<string> results = new List<string>();

    foreach (var x in y) // where y is what you are searching
    {
         if (x.Contains(term))
             results.Add(x);
    }

    return Json(results);
}
```